# Combining functions when used with usort?

Tags: php

I've got an array that contains weather values. I now have a working php script to sort the array by temperature and then pull out the maximum value for temperature, I then sort the array again by pressure and get the max pressure value.

```
function compare_pressure($a, $b)
{
    return strnatcmp($a['pressure'], $b['pressure']);
}

function compare_temp($a, $b)
{
    return strnatcmp($a['temp'], $b['temp']);
}

usort($table, 'compare_pressure');
$mypress = $table[0]['pressure'];

usort($table, 'compare_temp');
$mytemp = $table[0]['temp'];
```

I am now trying to combine the functions above so that I dont have to keep writing a new one for each compare, but I don't seem to be having any luck when used with usort.

I would need something like this, which doesnt work :(

```
function compare_temp($a, $b, $value)
{
    return strnatcmp($a[$value], $b[$value]);
}

 usort($table, 'compare_temp', 'temp');
```

Comment: why sort twice? you could just foreach() the array and do `if($cur > $prev)` testing for bothpressure and temp values. one loop over the array, rather than 2 full-blown sorts

Comment: Would this be the best way to do it - the array has around 15 values I need to sort with around 300 entries. I guess it would make it easier rather than having to sort 15 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways, in order of preference:

```
// Method 1 -- by object
class Comparitor {
    public function __construct($key) {
        $this->key = $key;
    }
    public function compare($a, $b) {
        return strnatcmp($a[$this->key], $b[$this->key]);
    }
}
usort($table, [new Comparitor('temp'), 'compare']);

// Method 2 -- anonymous function
function compare_by_key($a, $b, $key) {
    return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
}
usort($table, function ($a, $b) { return compare_by_key($a, $b, 'temp'); });

// Method 3 -- by global
function compare_by_global_key($a, $b) {
    global $key;
    return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
}
$key = 'temp';
usort($table, 'compare_by_global_key');
```

If you only needed the max, you could use:

```
function aggregate_by_key($table, $key, $aggregate = 'max') {
    return $aggregate(array_column($table, $key));
}
$maxTemp = aggregate_by_key($table, 'temp', 'max');
$minTemp = aggregate_by_key($table, 'temp', 'min');
$sumTemp = aggregate_by_key($table, 'temp', 'array_sum');
```

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that I not only need the max value but the corresponding time that is associated with that value.

Comment: @Greg: Ahh, that makes a big difference in approach! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking for max temp/pressure values, and not the whole records, extract the values first, and then sort:

```
$temps = array_column($weather, 'temp');
natsort($temps);
$max_temp = array_pop($temps);
```

Ref: [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), [shim for PHP 5.4-](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column).

Otherwise, there's no need to sort an array to find the maximum:

```
function max_by($ary, $fn) {
    $max = reset($ary);
    foreach($ary as $item)
        $max = $fn($max, $item) > 0 ? $max : $item;
    return $max;
}
```

and then:

```
$record_with_max_temp = max_by($weather, function($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp($a['temp'], $b['temp']);
});
```

This returns the whole record and not just the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
function createComparisonFunction($key) {
    return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
        return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
    };
}

usort($table, createComparisonFunction('pressure'));
usort($table, createComparisonFunction('temp'));
```

Having said, that, I'd rather use this approach to begin with:

```
$max = array_reduce(
    $table,
    function (array $max, array $value) {
        if (strnatcmp($max['temp'], $value['temp']) < 0) {
            $max['temp'] = $value['temp'];
        }
        if (strnatcmp($max['pressure'], $value['pressure']) < 0) {
            $max['pressure'] = $value['pressure'];
        }
        return $max;
    },
    ['temp' => null, 'pressure' => null]
);

echo $max['temp'];
echo $max['pressure'];
```

I'm not sure why you need `strnatcmp` really, those values should be integers, which would simplify the callback function to this:

```
    function (array $max, array $value) {
        $max['temp']     = max($max['temp'], $value['temp']);
        $max['pressure'] = max($max['pressure'], $value['pressure']);
        return $max;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - seems much simpler!

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to create a class to encaptulate the whole process:

```
class WeatherData{

    private $max_values;

    public function __construct($weather_array, $elements){

        foreach ($weather_array as $weather_item) {
            foreach($elements as $element){
                if(!isset($this->max_values[$element])){
                    $this->max_values[$element] = $weather_item[$element];
                }else{
                    if($this->max_values[$element] < $weather_item[$element]){
                        $this->max_values[$element] = $weather_item[$element];
                    }
                }
            }
        }    
    }

    public function __get($key){
        return $this->max_values[$key];
    }

}

$wa = array(
    array('pressure'=>11, 'temp'=>2),
    array('pressure'=>1, 'temp'=>22),
    array('pressure'=>7, 'temp'=>21),
    array('pressure'=>22, 'temp'=>33),
    array('pressure'=>16, 'temp'=>8),
);
$elements = array(
    'temp', 'pressure'
);
$wd = new WeatherData($wa, $elements);

echo 'max temp: '. $wd->temp . ' max pressure :' . $wd->pressure;
```

Live example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/kobe1Z